# Updating UI from background thread - how do I know that my GUI is not disposed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, dispose

I have a background thread which updates the UI once it's done. I tried to be as safe as I can, so that I don't call GUI which has been Disposed.

```
void DoInBackground()
{
    try 
    {
       string result = ServerSideProcess();
*       if (!IsDisposed && !Disposing)
*          BeginInvoke(new StringDelegate(UpdateText), result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
*       if (!IsDisposed && !Disposing)
*          BeginInvoke(new VoidDelegate(UpdateFailed));
    }
}


void UpdateText(string txt)
{
    if (!IsDisposed && !Disposing)
        textbox1.Text = txt;
}

void UpdateFailed() 
{
    if (!IsDisposed && !Disposing)
        textbox1.Text = "failed to get data from server";
}

override Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (components != null)
            components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

I think that I'm safe enough inside the GUI methods - Dispose() won't get called while i'm inside UpdateText(string) or UpdateFailed() because they both run in the same thread, so I'm assuming that checking for IsDisposing and later executing is good enough. But how can I know for sure that the parts in (*) won't get a Dispose() inbetween, which will result BeginInvoke get called on a disposing class, and eventually an application crash?

I tested it by adding Thread.Sleep(2000) between the (*) parts, putting breakpoints before and after the Thread.Sleep, and moving out of the control causing it to get Dispose()d before reaching BeginInvoke. the result - my application crashed. how can i know that the runtime won't give me this unfortunate context switching scenario?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a problem that is fully solved, for free, by the Backgroundworker.

Any reason not to use it?

Comment: The BackgroundWorker uses threadpool threads, does it not?  Some tasks are better served by having their own thread, either because they will spend a lot of time blocking, or because they use ThreadStatic data which should go away when they are done.

Comment: 'Stealing' one thread from the Pool is acceptable. ThreadStatic/ThreadLocal should be avoided anyway.

Comment: If one thread gets stolen from the pool and held for a long time, that won't affect things, but (1) how many things can hog "one" thread before it becomes a problem, and (2) if the pool happens to be backed up, one's request for a thread may be arbitrarily delayed.  As for ThreadStatic, it's not wonderful, but there are contexts where it can be the least evil way of doing things.

Comment: laziness is the main reason (the code is a little old). i didn't think it will solve my problem and it did. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd call that an exceptional condition- use a try/catch around the BeginInvokes to catch and explicitly handle the exception that gets thrown.

Comment: There are some unfortunate quirks in the way `InvokeRequired`, `BeginInvoke`, etc. are implemented, such that if you can't set a lock-guarded flag within your `Dispose` routine, there is no race-free way to do a `BeginInvokeUnlessWindowIsGone`.  You just have to do the `BeginInvoke` and swallow the exception.

Comment: @supercat agreed, that's why I think it's an exceptional case (and so the try/catch is justified).

Comment: From a caller side, yeah.  It's a design small, but the stink comes from the Framework's failure to recognize that a lot of BeginInvokes (and events) happen for the benefit of the target, rather than the invoker; similar stinks happen with events (e.g. because there is no `WeakEvent` or `WeakDelegate`).

Answer (score 0):

The following does not show me any error message when executed:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    Shown += Form1_Shown;
}

void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Dispose();
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //This is your second thread.
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //This runs when the second thread is finished. Update here.
    Text = "Done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you may be able to achieve clean shutdown by having the `Dispose` routine for the control acquire a lock, set a flag, and release the lock; your update routine should acquire the lock, do the `BeginInvoke` if the flag isn't set, and release the lock.  The key purpose of the lock is to ensure that once the update routine has decided to call the `BeginInvoke`, the control won't get disposed until the update happens.

That having been said, in a lot of ways I think it's cleaner to just do the `BeginInvoke` and swallow the exception that will occur if the control gets disposed from under you.  There really should be a `TryBeginInvoke` which would do a `BeginInvoke` and return `True` if the control is alive and otherwise return `False`, but alas there is not, nor is there any race-free way to create one without either injecting oneself into the control's `Dispose` process or letting an exception occur and stifling it.